# Click event not working in IE11

Tags: click, touch, internet-explorer-11, easeljs

i am shocked to see that

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
        var circle = new createjs.Shape();
        createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
        circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        circle.x = 100;
        circle.y = 100;
        circle.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { 
            alert('clicked'); 
        }, false);
        stage.addChild(circle);
        stage.update();
```

is not working in the IE11 on my window surface. Any substitute for this event so i can perform click function

Comment: Are you clicking on it with a mouse, or are you just tapping the touch screen?

Comment: i am tapping the screen

Comment: i am posting the code

Comment: so what type is `createjs`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - It's EaselJS I think, and it creates a custom graphics object, but that object should have an addEventListener, not sure if it's the native one or a custom eventListener though ?

Comment: I up-voted to get you out of negative 1. Why people down-vote a legitimate question is so annoying. I hardly ask questions anymore because it will just be down-voted unless amazingly clever and it is only the extra up-votes that keep you out of the negative.

Comment: @Shane.. yes correct , idk why questions are downvoted even without any explanatory coments

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8 and touch screens, the following should work

```
document.addEventListener("pointerdown", function (evt) { 
    alert('clicked'); 
}, false);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465891.aspx

`MSPointerDown` can be used with IE10, it has been deprecated in IE11+ in favor of `pointerdown`.

Comment: There seems to have [been issues](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806892/ie11-mspointerdown-not-firing-anymore) with this event and jQuery, but for addEventListener it should work for clicks and taps in MS systems, including Win 8.1 and IE.

Comment: if i write document.addeventlistener than it works fine. but never works with circle.addeventlistener

Comment: Then the version of addEventListener that cirle uses is probably a custom function that somehow differs from the standard one, or the circle object just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#circle").click(function(e) {
alert("clicked");
```

});
use jquery instead of javascript

Comment: this is not a  plane javascript or jquery